# VirtualBox NAT Port Forward Localhost or Host-only access Guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding, nat

I'd like to port forward my host's localhost at port 4431 to 443 so I can access websites on my Windows 10 guest.

However, it seems the NAT Network Adapter only supports explicit definition of the Host IP and gives me an error about forwarding rules not being valid.

My Host IP is dynamic based on the wireless I am logged into and I prefer not having to change the Host IP column every time I am on a new network.

I tried to setup Host-only adapter but could not find a good guide on setting that up: I could access the guest's localhost website with the new IP address provided by the adapter but not from the host.

[image]

Comment: It's strange that the NAT port forwarding rules UI does not support what the documentation states is supported via command-line. I ended up resolving my issue by using host-only adapter and just using DHCP server (so I didn't have to setup anything on the guest).